# Using abstract classes \ interfaces

Tags: java

I need to create an objects what l may to check by `instanceof` keyword.

Like

```
public class Example {
  private int create(GUIItemType type){
    if(type instanceof GUIItemTypeCommand){
      return 0;
    } else if (type instanceof GUIItemTypeSend){
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 2;
    }
  }
}
```

Whay i need use for create that? GUIItemTypeCommand class must extends GUIItemType class? GUIItemType class must be abstract?

Comment: I know that's not what you asked, but if you find yourself in this situation you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca l understood that is my error and i need help for understanding that system in java. In google i find only "cat extends Pet" and another what doesn\`t help anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `GUIItemType` as an `interface` and then make `GUIItemTypeCommand` and `GUIItemTypeSend` implement it.

```
interface GUIItemType {
    // default methods, abstract methods, public static final variables
}

class GUIItemTypeCommand implements GUIItemType {

}

class GUIItemTypeSend implements GUIItemType {

}
```

Comment: thank you very much!

Only one more quation, can i create empty GUIItemType class? Or l must to set methods etc?

Comment: `GUIItemType` can be empty. There are many examples of OOTB (Out Of The Box) interfaces which are empty e.g. [EventListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html), [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) etc.

Comment: Thank you! You very help me <3